# PHP: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (t_echo)

Tags: calculator

A user accesses the Calculation.html first and enters two numbers following message. Then, select the operation from the drop-down box. When the user clicks the button, the web page displays the correct result by sending the data to the PHP file for evaluating the result. I have the PHP code here and whenever I run the code I keep getting an error.

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Calculation Result</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php # handle_form.php


    $num1 = $_REQUEST['number1'];
    $num2 = $_REQUEST['number2'];
    $operator = $_REQUEST['operator'];



    if ($operator == 'add') {
         echo $result = $num1+$num2;
    }
       esleif( $operator == 'subtract') {
         echo $result = $num1-$num2;
       }
       esleif( $operator == 'multiply') {
        echo $result = $num1*$num2;
      }

      esle( $operator == 'divide') {
        echo $result = $num1/$num2;
      }


    echo "<p> The result is $result<p>";

    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Whats `esleif` and `esle`?

Comment: Syntax error change `esleif` to `elseif` and `esle` to `else`